# Can fulltext search work if the document type's value is empty in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, column-types

I create a fulltext search index on a varbinary column in SqlServer ,and add a type column for it.I want to know,If I leave the type column's value to be null or empty or ".",what will happen when I start fulltext searching?

```
  1, Will  SqlServer analysis the document type by varbinary value?
  2, Will the record be updated in fulltext catalog?
  3, Can fulltext search work in the record?
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen either way?  If you are doing a text search it wont return that record if it is NULL or just an empty string. You should do a quick test and let us know what the answer is.

Comment: I want some types of document not to participate fulltext search,fill catalog will not invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I known the answer now . I find the fulltext search log under MSSQL/LogSQLFT*******.LOG

I insert some documents in my table with extension's value empty,Full-text Auto population is started,but it will say "warning:No appropriate filter was found during full-text index poppulation for table or indexed view ***,some columns of the row were not indexed."

So the answer is

```
      1, Will  SqlServer analysis the document type by varbinary value?
          ----no,sqlserver know the document type only type the type column.
      2, Will the record be updated in fulltext catalog?
          ----no     
      3, Can fulltext search work in the record?
          ----no
```